# AEM 6.4.x + SAML authenticantion (Okta): How do I read (via Java) the SAML response from my SSO provider?

Tags: single-sign-on, aem, okta, aem-6

**TLDR:** Using Java (or other AEM related technology), how do I retrieve the username used to login and subsequently view a protected page?

---

We have protected some pages via login that uses our SSO provider (Oka). I would like to read the SAML response (or at least retrieve the username used to login).

We  want to customize some of the things that's displayed on the protected page.

**example:** retrieve and display the logged in user's firstname, lastname, department and other info that are stored in the HR database

How can this be done?

I've looked at cookies (and storage tab in Firefox in general) and cannot find anything there. The only place were I can see the SAML response is when using a browser tool (example: SAML-tracer).

I've searched the net and the results I've found is only about **setting up AEM to connect to a SSO provider** (**this part is already configured and working already**).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be reading this off of the SAML response. This should be read from the User profile. SAML authentication handler allows you to save attributes provided in SAML response onto the AEM user.

When the SAML Auth handler logs the user into AEM, the user principal is linked with all subsequent requests as long as he remains logged in. You can get the user information based on principal/authorizable in the request

```
UserPropertiesManager upm = resourceResolver.adaptTo(UserPropertiesManager.class);
Authorizable authorizable = resourceResolver.adaptTo(Authorizable.class);
UserProperties userProperties = upm.getUserProperties(authorizable, "profile");
```

https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/com/adobe/granite/security/user/UserProperties.html

While the SAML auth handler can save attributes from SAML response onto an AEM user; for it to work as intended on production, it can depend on number of factors like the number of publishers [to keep data in sync], the volume of users, session affinity etc..

In my experience in spite of the framework having solutions in the form of community user sync, encapsulated token support for dealing with session affinity etc.. it fails to work as advertised and you may want to rethink the use of SAML on the publisher and introduce a way to read this information from the true source with just the basic profile getting pulled into AEM. If this was just for the authoring environment it should still work

Comment: I want to get the username used which I can then used to query the HR system database. Let me try your. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: To get the user id use ResourceResolver#getUserID. The user id value will depend on the configuration of SAML auth handler as one of the attributes can be mapped to be the AEM user name

Comment: This is the correct way to do this in 6.x versions of AEM. Configure SAML in AEM and tell it which attibutes in the SAML assertion map to which AEM user profile attributes, then access them via the built-in APIs. Mapped attributes will be re-sync'd each time the user logs in. You may also need to do some configuration on the IdP (e.g. Okta) side to make sure it's passing all the relevant attributes to AEM (the Service Provider in SAML-speak).

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: This is not easy and I have not tested this. I have just de-compiled the SAML authentication handler and checked what is going on there.

You should know what you are doing and you should try to make it as rock-solid as possible. In general, working with the APIs surrounding authentication in AEM is quite cumbersome.

---

I don't think you are going to be able to get information like department etc. from a "standard" SAML token. But lets assume that this is part of the tokens payload.

You will have to store this information somewhere. Probably the users profile (e.g. `/home/users/a/<userid>/profile`).

I would think this is possible with `org.apache.sling.auth.core.spi.AuthenticationFeedbackHandler`. This handler will have access to the request, response and authentication info of the user. So you have to implement such a handler, which then will be called after the user authenticated.

The authentication info is basically just a map that contains keys with the relevant information. One such key should be `user.jcr.credentials`. For SAML this should be an instance of `com.adobe.granite.auth.saml.extidp.SamlCredentials`.

Those credentials contain "attributes" that you can read through `getAttribute()`. The attribute that contains the "raw SAML response" is called `samlResponse`. So this should give you what you are looking for:

```
private String getSamlResponse(final AuthenticationInfo authenticationInfo) {
    if (authenticationInfo == null) {
        return "";
    }

    Object credentialsObject = authenticationInfo.get("user.jcr.credentials");
    if (credentialsObject == null) {
        return "";
    }

    try {
        SamlCredentials credentials = (SamlCredentials) credentialsObject;
        String encryptedSamlResponse = credentials.getAttribute("samlResponse");
        if (encryptedSamlResponse == null || encryptedSamlResponse.trim().length() == 0) {
            return "";
        }

        return decryptSamlResponse(encryptedSamlResponse);
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        // Unable to cast "credentialsObject" to "SamlCredentials"
        return "";
    }
}
```

Note:

1. The above code uses `SamlCredentials`. This class is not publicly exported by the `com.adobe.granite.auth.saml` bundle. You have to de-compile the bundle and copy and paste that class to your own bundle.
2. You have to implement the `decryptSamlResponse` method using [CryptoSupport](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-5/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/com/adobe/granite/crypto/CryptoSupport.html).

If the SAML token does not contain the information you are looking for you could try to use the email address of the user to query some kind of external database that contains the information and then store it in the users profile.

Whatever you do, if you do this on a publisher and you have multiple publishers (as you usually should have), then you will also have to think about synching the user profile between those publishers or use sticky connection. As far as I can tell synching is kind of buggy and has a few problems and you might run into situations were the first request goes to publisher 1, the next request (shortly after) goes to publisher 2 that does not have the synced profile yet. It probably is better to use sticky connections.